# Android - creating personal wifi screen

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

I'm trying to create my own wifi screen where a list of clickable AP is shown to the user. the problem is that when the user click on an AP the device disconnect and then reconnects to the same AP and not the chosen one. Here is the code: (only the open networks part, and I'm trying to move from secured network to an open one)

```
         public void onClick(View v) {
                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                List<WifiConfiguration> configuredNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
                for (WifiConfiguration configuredNetwork : configuredNetworks) {
                    if (currSSID().equals(configuredNetwork.SSID)) { // I took care of the removel of the "" in configuredNetwork.SSID in my code  
                        configuredNetwork .allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                        wifiManager.disconnect();
                        wifiManager.enableNetwork(configuredNetwork.networkId, true);
                        wifiManager.reconnect();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `ScanResult` instead of `WifiConfiguration` and created a new configuration - conf with the wanted scan result as follows:

```
conf.SSID = "\"" + scanResult.SSID + "\"";
conf.BSSID = scanResult.BSSID;
conf.hiddenSSID = true;
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
int id = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(id, true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to move from secured network to an open one

Here the configuration must be changed before, so it's preferable to create a new one:

```
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"" + your_net_name + "\"";
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
```

and also you need to check if wifi is enabled first:

```
if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
```

also you have to save your current changes to `wifiManager` using `saveConfiguration()` after `reconnect()`:

```
wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
```

**So**, the whole way must be:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"" + your_net_name + "\"";
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
List<WifiConfiguration> configuredNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for (WifiConfiguration configuredNetwork : configuredNetworks) {
     if (currSSID().equals(configuredNetwork.SSID)) { // I took care of the removel of the "" in configuredNetwork.SSID in my code  
        //configuredNetwork .allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE); // you don't need it here
        wifiManager.disconnect();
        wifiManager.enableNetwork(configuredNetwork.networkId, true);
        wifiManager.reconnect();
        wifiManager.saveConfiguration(); // to save your new changes to the network
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Still not working, it disconnects from the current AP skip to the chosen one and right away goes back to the current. in enableNetwork you used configuredNetwork? or did you mean conf? Anyway both doesn't work.

Comment: yea they both the same, but I have to wonder, what if you connected to the opened one first and then try to convert to the secured one? did you try that ?